# How to make a make a arraylist in json if there is a single object inside the List?

Tags: java, json, web-services, jaxb, jersey

For a single Object inside the list the webservice is formatting the json as :

```
{
  "statusCode": "SUCCESS",
  "LocationData": {
    "userID": "85010352",
    "salesOrganisation": "AU10",
    "hospitalAccount": "0001016425",
    "Locations": {
      "locationDetails": {
        "consignmentFlag": "0",
        "itemData": {
          "itemDetails": [
     {
              "additionalConsignmentComment": "null",
              "boQuantity": "0",
              "initialConsignmentComment": "null",
              "materialCode": "SPB1233G",
              "maxExpectedStockLevel": "0",
              "maxPAR": "null",
              "minPAR": "1",
              "newBarcode": "",
              "persistentItemNote": "",
              "shelfSequenceData": {
                "shelfSequenceDetails": {
                  "countSequence": "81"
                }
              },
              "totalStockQuantity": "12",
              "vendorCode": "USAU"
            },
            {
              "additionalConsignmentComment": "null",
              "boQuantity": "0",
              "initialConsignmentComment": "null",
              "materialCode": "SPB5142G",
              "maxExpectedStockLevel": "0",
              "maxPAR": "null",
              "minPAR": "1",
              "newBarcode": "",
              "persistentItemNote": "",
              "shelfSequenceData": {
                "shelfSequenceDetails": {
                  "countSequence": "82"
                }
              },
              "totalStockQuantity": "10",
              "vendorCode": "USAU"
            },
            {
              "additionalConsignmentComment": "null",
              "boQuantity": "0",
              "initialConsignmentComment": "null",
              "materialCode": "SPB5223G",
              "maxExpectedStockLevel": "0",
              "maxPAR": "null",
              "minPAR": "6",
              "newBarcode": "",
              "persistentItemNote": "",
              "shelfSequenceData": {
                "shelfSequenceDetails": {
                  "countSequence": "83"
                }
              },
              "totalStockQuantity": "15",
              "vendorCode": "USAU"
            },
            {
              "additionalConsignmentComment": "null",
              "boQuantity": "0",
              "initialConsignmentComment": "null",
              "materialCode": "SPB5633G",
              "maxExpectedStockLevel": "0",
              "maxPAR": "null",
              "minPAR": "1",
              "newBarcode": "",
              "persistentItemNote": "",
              "shelfSequenceData": {
                "shelfSequenceDetails": {
                  "countSequence": "84"
                }
              },
              "totalStockQuantity": "11",
              "vendorCode": "USAU"
            }
          ]
        },
        "locationAccount": "102021EYE",
        "locationCountDate": "2013/07/25"
      }
    }
  },
  "ItemBarCodeData": null
}
```

As you can see here if there is only one single location the webservice is treating the Locations field in json as a single object , where as when there is multiple data the jersey formats the field as array with "[]" square brackets in place after

```
"Locations": [{
      "locationDetails": {
       }
     }];
```

I tried to find a solution to make the location as a list for single element but was not successful.Can anyone help me on this.

Comment: Do you control the web-service? Just make your code always return an Array, of size 1 if need be.

Comment: its not always of size one it may have multiple data.The problem comes when there is only one item returned

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis also the size is displayed as one when there is only one object inside the list